# The distance between the origin and the tangent to the curve $y = e^{2x} + x^2$ drawn at the point $x=0$ is?

Tags: derivatives, curves, tangent-line

and the tangent to the curve $y = e^{2x} + x^2$  drawn at the point $x=0$ is ?
I am not able to figure out what distance is he asking ?
It's the distance between origin and the point where tangent cuts x or y axis Or something else ?

Comment: The tangent to the curve is a line.  I think he wants the distance between the origin and that line.

Comment: The perpendicular distance?

Comment: Yes. That's right. So now do you know how to continue?

Comment: If it is so then I can find the point of tangent which is (0,1) and using distance formula I can found the distance. But by this way the answer is 1 which is not in the options.

Comment: Distance point to line -- need to get perpendicular to line from that point, only then get distance from point to foot of perpendicular.

Comment: Since the answers here are rendered incorrect after your edit of the question, and you have got the answer yourself. perhaps it should be closed. Or you should post your own answer to get some closure. Anyway, the edited question is much easier, and the answer (working mentally) is $\frac 1{\sqrt 5}$. Hope you got that too.

Comment: I have posted an answer to the edited question. You can use it to check your work. Also, the method of calculating the area of a right triangle in two ways to get the distance between a line and the origin is a useful "trick" in case you didn't already know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the tangent to the curve at $x=0$.

$y'(x) = 2e^{2x} + 2x$

$y'(0) = 2$

Next find the $y$-coordinate of the point on the curve for $x=0$.

$y(0) = 1$

Now find the equation of the tangent line.

$y-1 = 2(x-0)$

$y = 2x + 1$

Find the $y$ and $x$ intercepts, namely $y_0$ and $x_0$ of the tangent line.

$y_0 = y(0) = 1$.

$x_0$ occurs when $y = 0$ i.e. $x_0 = -\frac 12$.

Note that the points $(0,0), (x_0,0), (0,y_0)$ form a right triangle.

Find the area of this triangle one way, treating $|x_0|$ as the base and $|y_0|$ as the height.

Area $A = \frac 12 |x_0||y_0| = \frac 14$

Find the area of this triangle another way. Let the height $h$ be the required distance between the origin and the line, which means the base $b$ is the distance between $(x_0,0)$ and $(0,y_0)$.

$b = \sqrt{x_0^2 +y_0^2} = \frac 12{\sqrt 5}$

so $A = \frac 12 bh = \frac 14\sqrt 5 h$

Equating the two expressions for $A$ gives:

$h = \frac 1{\sqrt 5} = \frac 15 \sqrt 5$

Answer (score 1):

If the function is

$$y(x) =  e^{2^x} + x^2$$ and **not** $$y(x) =  e^{2x} + x^2,$$ then $$y(0) = e^{2^0} + 0 = e^1 = e$$

and we can build [the first derivative](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-derivative-of-2-x) ([the slope of the tangent](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/calculus/derivatives/what-is-meaning-of-first-order-derivative.php) at some $x$)

$$y'(x) = \ln(2) ~ 2^x ~ e^{2^x} + 2x$$

and evaluate it at $x=0$ ([the slope of the tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) at $x=0$)

$$y'(0) =\ln(2) ~ 2^0 ~ e^{2^0} + 0  =e~\ln(2).$$

The tangent line is ([we have the slope and we have a point](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html) $(0,y(0))=(0,e)$ on the line):

$$t(x) = y'(0)~x+y(0)= e~\ln(2) ~ x +e$$

The distance between the origin $(0,0)$ and this tangent line can for example be calculated by building another [line](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordequation.html) $p(x)$ which is [perpendicular to the tangent line](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/perpendicular-lines-and-slopes) and passes through the origin. The equation for that line is

$$p(x) = -x/(e~\ln(2))  $$

The intersection of these two lines (can be obtained by solving $t(x)=p(x)$ and) is at $$(x,y)=(-(e~\ln(2))^2/((e~\ln(2))^2+1), (e~\ln(2))/((e~\ln(2))^2+1))$$

The [distance between the origin and this intersection point](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Distance-Between-Two-Points) is ([pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), [euclidian distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance))

$$(e~\ln(2))/\sqrt{(e~\ln(2))^2+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$y_1=e^{2^x}2^x\ln2+2x$$

$$x=0,y=e,(y_1)_{x=0}=e\ln2$$

What is the equation of the tangent?

Do you know how to find the perpendicular distance of a straight line from a given point?

Comment: Sry sir, my mistake. Now I have edited the right equation.

Comment: @TECHNO,  Could you follow the method here? If yes, then you should be able to solve with the correct equation as well

Comment: got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this question i have used the formula for distance between a point and the line .Am I right?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzGik.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=e^{2x}+x^2$ $\in R$

$f'(x)=2e^{2x}+2x$, 
$f'(0)=2$, 
$f(0)=1$

Tangent line equation is: $y-f(0)=f'(0){x-0} \iff y-1=2x \iff 2x-y+1=0$

So, $(\epsilon): 2x-y+1$

The distance of origin from the line is given by: $d(O,\epsilon)=(\vert 2*0-1*0+1 \vert)/(\sqrt{2^2+(-1)^2})=1/\sqrt{5}=\sqrt{5}/5$

Therefore the distance is: $\sqrt{5}/5$